# Metal - How to adapt the vertexDescriptor created by Metal I/O to my MTLRenderPipelineState?

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, vertex-shader, apple-model-io

I am developing a Metal macOS app that displays my own 3D models and some other 3D model.obj I import through the `Model I/O`. I am getting some conflict between my own   `vertexDescriptor` and the `vertexDescriptor` embedded into the model.obj.

I have found a patch to the trouble creating a brand new `MTLRenderPipelineState` per each model.obj imported (with its own `vertexDescriptor`), but I think this is not the proper way to do. I cannot imagine that I have to create a brand new `MTLRenderPipelineState` per each model (read each "different `vertexDescriptor`") imported. Any clue to work with a unique `MTLRenderPipelineState` for all the models in the app?

Here's a sample case. I create my own `vertexDescriptor`

```
Buffer 0: 
            stepFunction = MTLVertexStepFunctionPerVertex 
            stride = 64 
            Attribute 0:     // Position
                offset = 0 
                format = MTLAttributeFormatFloat3 
            Attribute 1:     // Normal
                offset = 16 
                format = MTLAttributeFormatFloat3 
            Attribute 2:     // Texture Coords
                offset = 32 
                format = MTLAttributeFormatFloat2 
            Attribute 3:     // Vertex Color
                offset = 48 
                format = MTLAttributeFormatFloat4
```

and I use it to configure my `MTLRenderPipelineState` accordingly with my vertex shader MyVertexShader's argument

```
struct VertexIn
{
    float4 position[[attribute(0)]];
    float4 normal[[attribute(1)]];
    float2 uvTex[[attribute(2)]];
    float4 color[[attribute(3)]];
};
```

Everything works well with the models I create myself using always the same `VertexIn` structure. But when I import a model.obj file with `Model I/O` and automatically get this `vertexDescriptor`

```
Buffer 0: 
        stepFunction = MTLVertexStepFunctionPerVertex 
        stride = 32 
        Attribute 0:     // Position
            offset = 0 
            format = MTLAttributeFormatFloat3 
        Attribute 1:     // Normal 
            offset = 12 
            format = MTLAttributeFormatFloat3 
        Attribute 2:     // Texture Coords
            offset = 24 
            format = MTLAttributeFormatFloat2
```

the `stride` is 32 (mine above is 64), the 4th `attribute` (color) is missed, so the model.obj looks jerky on the `MTKView`.

So, I created a brand new `MTLRenderPipelineState` only to draw this model.obj using the model.obj's `vertexDescriptor` and my own vertex shader function **MyVertexShader**. Well, I got this error

```
*Error: Vertex attribute color(3) is missing from the vertex descriptor*
```

So I added the 4th `attribute` color to the model.obj `vertexDescriptor`

```
if(objVertexDescriptor.attributes[3].format == MTLVertexFormatInvalid)
{
    // add the color attribute to the model.obj vertexDescriptor

    objVertexDescriptor.attributes[3].format = MTLVertexFormatFloat4;
    objVertexDescriptor.attributes[3].offset = sizeof(simd_float3) + sizeof(simd_float3) + sizeof(simd_float3);
    objVertexDescriptor.attributes[3].bufferIndex = 0;
}
```

then I created a brand new `MTLRenderPipelineState` with this `objVertexDescriptor` and my own vertex shader function **MyVertexShader**, and the model.obj finally looked well on the `MTKView`.

I feel that what I'm doing it's just a bad patch to this trouble and I think there should be a better and reusable way to solve the conflict hopefully using the same `MTLRenderPipelineState` for all the models. I can't accept I should create a new pipeline per each model the user will import. Any idea?

Comment: You don't need to create a pipeline per user import, but you do need to create a pipeline for each unique combination of properties in the render pipeline descriptor. I think a good solution to this problem is running a conversion pass before importing a model to make its vertex layout the same for a couple categories of meshes, for example, one vertex layout for static meshes, and one for skinned.

Comment: This is generally a problem not only with vertex descriptors, but with any permutations in shaders, such as using too many function constants or defines inside the shader, which will lead to a combinatoric explosion of when you have to compile an enormous amount of pipelines just to start the application.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy - Thank you. That's sound wise and practicable. My guess is how to convert the model to match my vertexDescription. As I have shown above I have already found how to add the color attribute, but I can't guess how to convert the 32-stride into a 64-stride. Maybe creating  new mesh/submesh buffer and filling it using my vertex layout, then deleting the original buffer? I have already found the way to access the vertexBuffer and scale each position coordinate. Now I should try to replace the buffers with my own schema (Float3, Float3, Float2, Float4). Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Yes, you would need to create a new vertex buffer and transform the existing data there in general case. I think Model I/O has some built in vertex transform capabilities, but I haven't used them

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. When I create the `MDLAsset`, I pass my own `mDefaultMDLVertexDescriptor` I created earlier and use all over my code. This forces the asset to adopt that vertexDescriptor.

```
MDLAsset    *objAsset = [[MDLAsset alloc] initWithURL:objURL
                vertexDescriptor:mDefaultMDLVertexDescriptor bufferAllocator:bufferAllocator];
```

So even the `MDLMesh` and the `MTKMesh` created from the asset get that vertexDescriptor

```
MDLMesh     *objMDLMesh = (MDLMesh*)[objAsset objectAtIndex:0];
    
    self.mMTKMesh = [[MTKMesh alloc] initWithMesh:objMDLMesh device:self.mDevice error:&error];
```

You could verify the mesh has that vertexDescriptor with

```
NSLog(@"self.mMTKMesh.vertexDescriptor %@\r", [MTKMetalVertexDescriptorFromModelIO(self.mMTKMesh.vertexDescriptor) description]);
```

and even with

```
NSLog(@"self.mMTKMesh.vertexDescriptor.attributes %@", self.mMTKMesh.vertexDescriptor.attributes);
```